# Can lowercasing a UTF-8 string cause it to grow?

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, uppercase, lowercase

I'm helping out with someone writing some code to compare UTF-8 strings in a case-insensitive way.  The scheme they are using is to uppercase the strings and then compare.  The input strings can all fit in a 255 byte array.  The output string similarly must fit in a 255 byte array.

I'm not a UTF-8 or Unicode expert, but I think this this scheme can't work for all strings.  My understanding is that either lower casing or upper casing a UTF-8 string can result in the output string being longer (byte array wise), and as such changing case is probably not the best way to attack this problem.  I'm trying to demonstrate the difficulty by giving a few strings that will not work with this design.

For example, take a string of the character U+0587 repeated 100 times.  U+0587 takes two bytes in UTF-8, so the overall length of the byte array for the string is 200 bytes (ignoring the trailing null for now).  If that string is uppercased, however, it becomes U+0535 U+0552, and each of those takes two bytes, for a total of 4 bytes.  The 200 byte array is now 400 bytes, and cannot be stored in the limited space available.

So here's my question: I gave an example of a lowercase character needing more space to store when uppercased.  Are there any examples of an uppercase character needing more space to store when lowercased?  The locale is always en_US.UTF-8 in this case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It can depend on which normalization form you're using as well.  For example, if you have a Titlecase letter and you change it to lowercase, you might get a new single codepoint, or you might decompose it into two lowercase letters.

Comment: Case-insensitive comparison cannot be done by converting the text to either uppercase or lowercase. There are languages where it doesn't work. Just Google "Turkey Test" for the most simple examples. The Unicode standard describes how it's done correctly. And it has been implemented in many programming languages. What's the reason for writing a new implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Examples from my environment:

```
U+023A Ⱥ    U+023E Ⱦ
```

There are several related factors that could cause variation. You already pointed out one:

1. The locale that you specify will affect the casing of characters that that locale is concerned with.
2. The version of the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository that your library uses.
3. The version of the Unicode Character Database that your library uses.

These aren't fixed targets because we can expect that there will be future versions and that there will be users using characters from them.

Ultimately, this comes down to your environment and to practical purpose this has.